# Calculation of the $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$ using contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis

I am studying complex variables. In Gamelin I found the following proof for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$ using contour integration here:

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

1. I have some basic questions, about the integral on the left in the second line being the sum of the two integrals on the right, i.e.,

- How is the $\int_{\partial D_{R}} \frac{dZ}{1+z^2} = \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} + \int_{T_{R}} \frac{dz}{1+z^2}$? The area under the first integral on the right already includes the area enclosed? I am a bit confused.

2. Why is he using this choice of contour? What if I choose a circle? I know if the circle includes both singularities it will go to zero. But I am not very clear.
3. How is the ML estimate $\leq \frac{1}{R^2 -1}$? I expect it to be $\frac{1}{1+R^2}$

Comment: How is $\int_{\partial D_{R}} \frac{dz}{1+z^2} = \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{dx}{1+x^2} + \int_{\Gamma_{R}} \frac{dz}{1+z^2}$?   Well, the border ${\partial D_{R}}$ consists of the real interval $[-R,R]$ and the semicircle ${\Gamma_{R}} $

Comment: Sorry this is a silly question @J.W.Tanner - but the area under $\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ already overlaps with $\int_{T_{R}} \frac{1}{1+z^2}$?

Comment: think of it as a contour integral

Comment: The first question is equivalent to $$\int_a^c f(x)\, dx = \int_a^b f(x)\, dx + \int_b^c f(x)\, dx$$  We cannot ignore part of the contour on the right of your identity, same as we cannot ignore one of the subintervals in the right of this identity

Answer (score 4):

1. Firstly, please note the contour integrals are evaluated on curves, not *'surfaces'*; i.e., we are not evaluating the integral on the semi-circular region (described in the excerpt from Gamelin as $D_R$), but on the curve bounding the region ($\partial D_R$), going in the anti-clockwise direction. $$\int_{\partial D_R}{\frac{dz}{1+z^2}}=\int_{-R}^{R}{\frac{dx}{1+x^2}}+\int_{\Gamma_R}{\frac{dz}{1+z^2}}$$ is simply breaking up the curve into two parts -

   - the straight line from $-R$ to $R$.
   - the semi-circle $\Gamma_R$.

   and evaluating the integral on the two separate parts.
2. You can very well choose a circle $\mathbb{T}_R$ of radius $R$ instead. However, integrating on the circle won't tell you anything about the value of the integral on the real line, simply because the real line isn't part of your chosen curve (or *contour*) - the circle.

   Also, as you've said - the integral on this *contour*, the circle $\mathbb{T}_R$ (not on the open disk of radius R - $\mathbb{D}_R$) will be zero. Can you prove that without using residues? (**hint:** use the symmetry of the contour)

   Nonetheless, you can choose other families of contours that include at least part of the real line in each contour; and try to evaluate the integral. It is just so that this contour makes the ML estimate easier. You can also try integrating anti-clockwise on a square contour with vertices at $\{-R,R,R+2iR,-R+2iR\}$; and check your answer.

   *Working Advice: As far as getting ML-estimates is concerned, it is usually easier to work with square or rectangular contours for exponential, sin, or cosine functions; and with circular, semicircular, and similar radial contours for polynomial functions.*
3. You have gotten the inequality reversed. The triangle inequality says $$\lvert\lvert z_1\rvert-\lvert z_2\rvert\rvert\leqslant \lvert z_1+z_2\rvert\leqslant \lvert z_1\rvert+\lvert z_2\rvert$$ Putting $z_1=z^2; z_2 = 1$, you get $\lvert\lvert z\rvert^2-1\rvert\leqslant \lvert z^2+1\rvert\leqslant \lvert z^2\rvert+1$; thence, for $R>1$; $$\frac{1}{R^2-1}\geqslant \frac{1}{\lvert z^2+1\rvert}\geqslant \frac{1}{R^2+1}$$ Nonetheless, as far as this problem is concerned - this is a rather minor detail; as the main point of the ML-estimates is to estimate the order of magnitude of the integral - which, here, is $\sim \frac{1}{R} $.

Comment: Thank you @TeebroProkash for the excellent explanation. I have two replies. For 2, if I choose the upper contour in the clockwise direction and the lower contour in the counter clockwise direction - then it can go to zero, and we can do this without residues. But why should I choose that orientation? Also, with respect to you advice on contours - thats really useful, but I dont see exactly why. For example, if I choose a rectangular contour of length 2R for $\int f(z)=1/e^z dz$ then I have the ML to be $|4R^2/e^R|, which goes to zero as R goes to infnity. But I dont see an advantage(contour)

Comment: Firstly, the integral on $\mathbb{T}_R$ is to be evaluated entirely in the counter-clockwise direction. Also, the integral you've described is not zero (*evaluate it!*). 

Secondly, have you tried proving the ML-estimate for $f=\frac{1}{e^z}$ with a semicircular contour? Please try.